# I need to get the control choices to sanitize_callback

Tags: theme-customizer, sanitization

**Code**

Currently, I'm working project to automatically generate all my theme customizer options with simple array.

```
'nav_font_style' => array(
    'default_options'  => array(
        1                   => 'default',),
    'css'               => "    nav#for-mobile h1 { font-family: $",
    'stylesheet_handle' => 'semperfi-navigation',
    'label'             => __('Font', 'semper-fi-lite'),
    'description'       => array(
        1                   => '', ),
    'panel_title'       => __('Navigation', 'semper-fi-lite'),
    'panel_priority'    => 1,
    'priority'          => 10,
    'section_title'     => __('Menu Title', 'semper-fi-lite'),
    'section_priority'  => 10,
    'selector'          => 'nav#for-mobile h1',
    'type'              => 'font'),
```

This array has everything needed to generate a theme option. Bellow is the loop that it will run through.

```
            // Add a font selector to Customizer
        if ($values['type'] == 'font') {

            $wp_customize->add_setting( $option . '_' . $i, array(
                'default'           => 'Default',
                'sanitize_callback' => 'semperfi_sanitize_css', ) );

            $wp_customize->add_control( $option . '_' . $i . '_control', array(
                'section'           => str_replace( "~", $semperfi_customizer_multi_dimensional_array[$i], $section_title_transformed ),
                'label'             => $values['label'],
                'description'       => $values['description'][$i],
                'priority'          => $values['priority'],
                'type'              => 'select',
                'settings'          => $option . '_' . $i,
                'stylesheet_handle' => $values['stylesheet_handle'],
                'choices'           => $finalized_google_font_array));

        }
```

When I go the sanitize_callback I'm having issues using this to access all the choices like it's explained on [How to get input_attrs in the sanitize function?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308248/how-to-get-input-attrs-in-the-sanitize-function)

```
function semperfi_sanitize_css( $input , $setting ) {

set_theme_mod( 'semperfi_testing' , $setting->manager->get_control( 'nav_font_style_1' )->input_attrs );

return $input;
```

}

The above sanitize function is just for testing but I really need to access the handle so that I can apply CSS to the correct sheet style.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the input_attrs, you need choices. This is what I do:

```
function mytheme_sanitize_choice( $input, $setting ) {
    $control = $setting->manager->get_control( $setting->id );
    $valid = $control->choices;
    return array_key_exists( $input, $valid ) ? $input : $setting->default;
}
```

Comment: I'm doing way more than checking if the 'choice' is in the array. Going to have separate theme mod where I build out the individual inline sheet style for each CSS handle. this is part of a heavy-duty option customizer generator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution... figures I get it after I post it.

```
// Add a font selector to Customizer
            if ($values['type'] == 'font') {

                $wp_customize->add_setting( $option . '_' . $i, array(
                    'default'           => 'Default',
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'semperfi_sanitize_css', ) );

                $wp_customize->add_control( $option . '_' . $i , array(
                    'choices'           => $finalized_google_font_array,
                    'description'       => $values['description'][$i],
                    'input_attrs'       => array(
                            'stylesheet_handle' => $values[ 'input_attrs' ][ 'stylesheet_handle' ],
                            'css'               => $values[ 'input_attrs' ][ 'css' ], ),
                    'label'             => $values['label'],
                    'priority'          => $values['priority'],
                    'section'           => str_replace( "~", $semperfi_customizer_multi_dimensional_array[$i], $section_title_transformed ),
                    'settings'          => $option . '_' . $i,
                    'type'              => 'select', ) );

            }

        function semperfi_sanitize_css( $input , $setting ) {

        set_theme_mod( 'semperfi_testing' , $setting->manager->get_control( $setting->id )->input_attrs[stylesheet_handle] );

        return $input;
        // just testing right now

    }
```